# RShiny: Hiding / Showing a Table based on Radio Buttons

Tags: r, shiny, hide, show, dt

I have two tables and I'm trying to show one at a time based on user input in radio buttons. If the input from the radio buttons is "table", i'd like to show table1. If the input is `else` i'd like to show table2.

```
  observeEvent(input$visuBtn,{
    req(input$visuBtn)
    print(input$visubtn)
    if(input$visuBtn == "table"){
      hide("table2")
      #DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
      renderUI(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table1")
      )
    }else{
      print("Should show table2")
      # removeUI(
      #   selector = "table"
      # )
      renderUI(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
      )
      #DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
      #show("table2")
    }
  })
```

I've tried doing this by showing and hiding the two tables and can't figure out how to get that to work. I"ve also tried using `renderUI` as well. What would be the best methodology to go about this?

```
     mainPanel(
       tabsetPanel(id = "sim.tabset",
         tabPanel(title = "Results",
                  # tableOutput("table")
                  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
                  DT::dataTableOutput("table2")


         ),

         )
```

Comment: Could u please provide the ui code?

Comment: @TarJae I think I may have added in what you are looking for. I am extremely new to R, so my apologies if that is wrong. I also deleted a lot of non important code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your app, you can toggle the visibility of the table in the frontend with a little bit of javascript. In the UI, create a button and wrap the dataTableOutput in a generic container.

```
# some where in your UI
actionButton("toggleTable", "Toggle Table"),
tags$div(
    id = "tableContainer",
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)
...
```

There are many ways to toggle the visibility of an element (changing the display properties, toggling css classes, modifying other attributes, etc.). The following function toggles the html attribute `hidden` when the button is clicked. This can be defined in the UI using the `tags$script` function or loaded from an external javascript file.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('toggle');
const elem = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (elem.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
        elem.removeAttribute('hidden');
    } else {
        elem.setAttribute('hidden', '');
    }
});
```

In the server, render the datatable as normal and you can remove the toggling (unless you need additional things to happen when the button is clicked).

Here is the full example.

```r
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui = tagList(
        tags$main(
            id = "main",
            tags$h1("Collapsible Table Example"),
            actionButton("toggleTable", "Toggle Table"),
            tags$div(
                id = "tableContainer",
                DT::dataTableOutput("table")
            )
        ),
        tags$script(
            type = "text/javascript",
            "
            const btn = document.getElementById('toggleTable');
            const elem = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
            btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                if (elem.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
                    elem.removeAttribute('hidden');
                } else {
                    elem.setAttribute('hidden', '');
                }
            });
            "
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
            data.frame(
                group = sample(c("A", "B"), 20, replace = TRUE),
                x = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 50, sd = 2),
                y = rnorm(n = 20, mean = 50, sd = 2)
            )
        })
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I opted to go with a simple solution, just having one table that renders based on the choice of the radiobuttons. Meaning the if/else is just within the renderDataTable function

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("Buttons", "CHOOSE!", choices = c("MTCARS", "IRIS")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("THETABLE")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$THETABLE<-DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$Buttons)
    if(input$Buttons == "MTCARS") {
      DT::datatable(mtcars)
    } else {
      DT::datatable(iris)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Alternatively, you could use conditional panel, so it shows the table based on the radiobutton selection:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("Buttons", "CHOOSE!", choices = c("MTCARS", "IRIS")),
  conditionalPanel("input.Buttons == 'MTCARS'", 
                   DT::dataTableOutput("TABLEMTCARS")
                   ),
  conditionalPanel("input.Buttons == 'IRIS'",
                   DT::dataTableOutput("TABLEIRIS"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$TABLEMTCARS<-DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars)
  })
  
  output$TABLEIRIS<-DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```